# NServiceBus: Message handler types not loading correctly when configuring via code

Tags: nservicebus

After changing the Subscriber2 project in the PubSub sample, I am getting this error when a message is received by this subscriber:

> ERROR
>   NServiceBus.Unicast.Transport.Msmq.MsmqTransport
>   [(null)] <(null)> - Could not extract
>   message data.
>   System.TypeLoadException: Could not
>   handle type 'MyMessages.EventMessage'.

I changed the EndpointConfig.cs file to this:

```
using NServiceBus;

namespace Subscriber2
{
    public class EndpointConfig : IConfigureThisEndpoint, AsA_Server, IWantCustomInitialization
    {
        public void Init()
        {
            Configure.With(new[] { typeof(EventMessageHandler), typeof(NServiceBus.Unicast.Transport.CompletionMessage) })
                .DefaultBuilder()
                .XmlSerializer()
                .UnicastBus()
                .DoNotAutoSubscribe();
        }
    }
}
```

Does anyone know why this doesn't work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not specify your message type in the list.  If you use this overload of With() you will have to supply all types.  I would recommend pointing to a specific assembly instead and letting NSB scan it for the correct types.  Alternatively you could do nothing and let it scan the bin directory.

Comment: Looks like I listed the type of the handler, and not the message.  My real question then is, is there any way to explicitly specify the handler?  I want to be able to determine the handler at runtime, and I worry that if I have multiple handlers of the same type it would get confused.

Comment: You would have to add a condition to the container NSB uses.  To achieve this you can pass your personal instance of the container into NSB to use.  This way you have full control over what gets loaded.